# qtranslatex and yoast seo keywords

Tags: javascript, wordpress, translation, qtranslate-x, yoast

Having some trouble with the QTranslate and Yoast SEO integration plugin.
https://github.com/qTranslate-Team/wp-seo-qtranslate-x

Apparently they are not going to update it and there is an issue with the Focus Keywords not working in each page. It is using the vesion 1.1.1
Attempting to use the version in the Github which is version 1.2 gave some Javascript errors.

Are there alternatives or other plugins to making it work?

Answer (score 0):

You can use Qtranslate-x and All in one seo plugin. I am using it right now in my website.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. It shall be considered.